# Regex to add trailing slash to URLs in a certain subdirectory

Tags: mysql, regex, url, replace

I have a MySQL database on a WordPress site where I want to find all the posts in a certain table that contain a URL (within a specific subdirectory) that doesn't have a trailing slash and add one.

For example, find URLs like:

```
https://www.example.com/directory/test
```

And change them to:

```
https://www.example.com/directory/test/
```

Some already have a trailing slash, so I don't want to add// on the end of those.

The directory they are in is constant so the URL will always contain `/directory/`*

Any ideas on what regular expression I should use? I am using the Better Search and Replace Plugin

https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/doc/find-and-replace/#regex-find-replace

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for not capturing the string without "/" if it's present

```
/(?>\/$)/
```